# Preview page Image orientation

Tags: php, html, css, image, orientation

I picked up some work updating images on a website that someone else had created managed previously.
I determined how it was laid out enough to get what needed to be done done.
However, two images I added are showing in landscape orientation on the preview page but when the image is clicked on it shows properly in the portrait orientation.
[www.artbyheenan.com/art.php](http://www.artbyheenan.com/art.php)
Its the first two images, if anyone can take a look and give me some input I'd appreciate it.
Initially I thought it may have been the image size as it was rather large and I resized it to 200kb but still the same.

Comment: It also does it in IE and Edge. I suspect it may be something in the css. I tried removing the EXIF data from the link below, but the result is still the same.

Comment: It also does it in IE and Edge as well. I tried removing the EXIF data from the link below, but the result is still the same. Also tried removing any coding in the css that looked to do with img position/location but didn't change either.

Comment: I also found in the file directory art.html and have been playing with it, it is also displaying the image in the wrong orientation after removing EXIF data. I'm testing in Chrome, IE, and Edge. http://artbyheenan.com/art.html

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the images meta/exif data and a known issue in the browsers.
- https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/squoosh/issues/299
- [Chrome Image EXIF Orienation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401203/chrome-image-exif-orienation-issue)

The best solution right now is to re-save the image in photoshop or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Using Gimp I opened then exported and wala!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your images have EXIF data that has rotation set to 90º CCW.

If you delete the EXIF data, they will display properly.

You can do that here: [Remove EXIF data online](https://www.verexif.com/en/)

Comment: Tried this a couple times, viewed and removed but didn't alter orientation. Thanks tho